# Swift get json data into struct and populate pickerViews

Tags: json, swift, uipickerview, decode

I'm coding an app where I want to populate 2 dependent UIPickerViews with car brands and car models.

I'm parsing the following json file in input containing
the inputs for car models :

```
[{
"brand": "ALFA ROMEO",
"models": [
    "Mito (145)",
    "145/146 (930)",
    "147 (937)",
    "Giulietta (940)",
    "155 (167)",
    "156 (932)",
    "159 (939)",
    "Giulia (620)",
    "164 (164)",
    "166 (136)",
    "GTV / Spider (916)",
    "Brera",
    "Spider (939)",
    "GT Coupé (937)",
    "4C (643)",
    "Stelvio (630)"
]},
{
"brand": "AMC",
"models": [
  "Alliance",
  "Concord",
  "Eagle",
  "Encore",
  "Spirit"
]
},
...
]
```

I want to get the list of car brands on the former UIPickerView
and feed the latter following the user's choice on the former...

I used the following struct to parse and get jsondata

```
struct carBrands : Codable {
let brand : String
let models : [String]
}
```

This function allows me to parse json and get on the 
cars object which depends on the struct

```
var cars:carBrands?
```

And here the json decoder

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "carModels", withExtension: "json")
    /*let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    let jsonResponse = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!)*/

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response
        , error) in

        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let carData = try decoder.decode(carBrands.self, from: data)
            print(carData)
            self.cars = carData
            return
        }catch let err {
            print("Err", err)
        }
    }.resume()
```

I get this error on xcode

```
Err typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>,     Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Could you please show le the tricks to populate correctly my uipickerviews ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your JSON is a NSArray at top level. So `try decoder.decode(carBrands.self, from: data)` should be `try decoder.decode([carBrands].self, from: data)`

Comment: Thank you, I already tried that , but swift says : [Cannot assign value of type '[carBrands]' to type 'carBrands?']. What modification should I make to make the struct suit with the data ?

Comment: change `var cars:carBrands?` to `var cars: [carBrands]?`. Your `struct carBrands` represents a single brand and a number of models for that brand. you want to work with (and your JSON will contain) a list of car brands. so `[carBrands]` indicates an array of that type

Comment: It works great thank you :) but now I want to get the array and populate my picker views. Any idea on what get the information and populate that ?

Comment: Please name structs with starting capital letter according to the Swift naming convention. And name the struct in singular form. Semantically each item in `cars` represents one `CarBrand`, not one `CarBrands`.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I have this array on my self.cars

```
▿ Optional<Array<carBrands>>
  ▿ some : 70 elements
    ▿ 0 : carBrands
      - brand : "ALFA ROMEO"
      ▿ models : 16 elements
    - 0 : "Mito (145)"
    - 1 : "145/146 (930)"
    - 2 : "147 (937)"
    - 3 : "Giulietta (940)"
    - 4 : "155 (167)"
    - 5 : "156 (932)"
    - 6 : "159 (939)"
    - 7 : "Giulia (620)"
    - 8 : "164 (164)"
    - 9 : "166 (136)"
    - 10 : "GTV / Spider (916)"
    - 11 : "Brera"
    - 12 : "Spider (939)"
    - 13 : "GT Coupé (937)"
    - 14 : "4C (643)"
    - 15 : "Stelvio (630)"
▿ 1 : carBrands
  - brand : "AMC"
  ▿ models : 5 elements
    - 0 : "Alliance"
    - 1 : "Concord"
    - 2 : "Eagle"
    - 3 : "Encore"
    - 4 : "Spirit"
▿ 2 : carBrands
  - brand : "Aston Martin"
  ▿ models : 9 elements
    - 0 : "DB7"
    - 1 : "DB9"
    - 2 : "DBS"
    - 3 : "Lagonda"
    - 4 : "Rapide"
    - 5 : "V12 Vantage"
    - 6 : "V8 Vantage"
    - 7 : "Vanquish"
    - 8 : "Virage"
```

I have to take all the car brands on a list and then following user's choice populate another picker with the car models. Could you tell me how to do that please ?

Excuse, I am a beginner. Thank you for taking time to answer. :)